# Custom application metrics alternative to FnordMetric

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metrics

I'm currently displaying metrics for my application using FnordMetric (https://github.com/paulasmuth/fnordmetric).

As pretty as it is, documentation is lacking and doing things such as importing historical data is a pain.

I'm curious if there are alternative tools (commercial is fine also) that do exactly what FnordMetric does, but with a larger/active community and much better documentation.

Answer (score -3):

The [Ruby Toolbox page for Fnordmetric](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/fnordmetric) suggests several options with [New Relic RPM](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/rpm) the highest rated. One of those may work well for you.